# i am working with zend queue i wrote a piece of code in bootstrap its showing an error can anyone help me

Tags: zend-framework, queue

I am new to Zend Framework and I am trying to work with `Zend_Queue`.  I placed this piece of code in the bootstrap but it is throwing an exception.  The code in Bootstrap.php:

```
<?php
class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap {

    protected function _initDatabase() {
        $options = array(
            'name' => 'queue',
            'driverOptions' => array (
                'host'          => '127.0.0.1',
                'port'          => '3306',
                'username'      => 'root',
                'password'      => '',
                'dbname'        => 'queue',
                'type'          => 'pdo_mysql'
            )
        );
    }

    protected function _initQueue() {
        $options = $this->getOptions();
        $queueAdapter = new Zend_Queue_Adapter_Db($options['queue']);

        Zend_Registry::getInstance()->queueAdapter = $queueAdapter;
    }
}
```

And this is the error I am getting:

```
Fatal error: 
  Uncaught exception 'Zend_Queue_Exception' with message 'Adapter options must be an array or Zend_Config object' in
C:\wamp\library\ZendFramework\library\Zend\Queue\Adapter\AdapterAbstract.php:110 Stack trace: #0 
C:\wamp\library\ZendFramework\library\Zend\Queue\Adapter\Db.php(83): Zend_Queue_Adapter_AdapterAbstract->__construct(NULL, NULL) #1
C:\wamp\www\queue2\application\Bootstrap.php(28): Zend_Queue_Adapter_Db->__construct(NULL) #2 C:\wamp\library\ZendFramework\library\Zend\Application\Bootstrap\BootstrapAbstract.php(667): Bootstrap->_initQueue() #3
C:\wamp\library\ZendFramework\library\Zend\Application\Bootstrap\BootstrapAbstract.php(620): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->_executeResource('queue') #4
C:\wamp\library\ZendFramework\library\Zend\Application\Bootstrap\BootstrapAbstract.php(584): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->_bootstrap(NULL) #5 
C:\wamp\library\ZendFramework\library\Zend\Application.php(355): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->bootstrap(NULL) #6
C:\wamp\w in C:\wamp\library\ZendFramework\library\Zend\Queue\Adapter\AdapterAbstract.php on line 110
```

Answer (score 1):

Try moving the `$options` you are setting into the same method with `_initQueue()` and pass the entire `$options` array instead of `$options['queue']`.  It doesn't look like `$options['queue']` is defined unless you have something in `application.ini` for it.

Try:

```
<?php
class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap {

    protected function _initQueue() {
        $options = array(
            'name'          => 'queue',
            'driverOptions' => array (
                'host'          => '127.0.0.1',
                'port'          => '3306',
                'username'      => 'root',
                'password'      => '',
                'dbname'        => 'queue',
                'type'          => 'pdo_mysql'
            )
        );

        $queueAdapter = new Zend_Queue('Db', $options);

        Zend_Registry::getInstance()->queueAdapter = $queueAdapter;
    }
}
```